# Minify razor html pages with nuglify or Web Optimizer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying out [ASP.NET Core Web Optimizer](https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer) which uses [NUglify](https://github.com/xoofx/NUglify) under the hood. It works perfectly for `js` and `css` and apparently has support for `html` as well, but I can't get it to work with razor cshtml. Adding `services.AddWebOptimizer(p => p.MinifyHtmlFiles());` doesn't seem to do anything and moving `app.UseWebOptimizer();` to after `app.UseMvc();` doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

using library called WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5 will help

nuget package link - https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5/

ref -https://stackoverflow.com/a/65879818/9641914

Note : mentioned library is for .net 5