# How to minify in .net core mvc view?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, minify, bundling-and-minification

On the website I made with .net core mvc. When we open the site and click on the page source view, how can we do the long codes as shown in the second picture, in the form of minify?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to minify, uglify, comiple and clearly make view source to be the most unclearly to decrease hackers readability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019544/how-to-minify-uglify-comiple-and-clearly-make-view-source-to-be-the-most-uncle)

Comment: I don't use node.js. The solution here offers node.js. Also, I minify it with css and js bundle minify. I want to show the views coming from the page source part of the active site as in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Adding Web Markup Min to ASP.NET Core application

`WebMarkupMin` is a very mature minifier, not just for HTML but also XML and XHTML, as well as script and style tags embedded in your HTML. They provide multiple NuGet packages for hooking up your ASP.NET applications, both for ASP.NET 4.x using MVC, HttpModules, WebForms and ASP.NET Core.

**Step 1. Install package WebMarkupMin.AspNetCoreX**

My project is ASP.NET Core 5, so I choose to install `WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5`.

[image]

**Step 2. Register in your application's `Startup.Configure` method**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseWebMarkupMin();

        app.UseRouting();
        ...
    }
```

**Step 3. Register services to the IoC container**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddWebMarkupMin(
            options =>
            {
                options.AllowMinificationInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
                options.AllowCompressionInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
            })
            .AddHtmlMinification(
                options =>
                {
                    options.MinificationSettings.RemoveRedundantAttributes = true;
                    options.MinificationSettings.RemoveHttpProtocolFromAttributes = true;
                    options.MinificationSettings.RemoveHttpsProtocolFromAttributes = true;
                })
            .AddHttpCompression();
    }
```

**Test result**

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

> Configure bundling and minification

The MVC and Razor Pages project templates provide a solution for bundling and minification consisting of a JSON configuration file. A third-party tool is a great fit when your development workflow requires processing beyond bundling and minification—such as linting and image optimization. By using design-time bundling and minification, the minified files are created prior to the app's deployment. Bundling and minifying before deployment provides the advantage of reduced server load. You can check details from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x#configure-bundling-and-minification) here.

Comment: Thanks I got a full answer to my question.

Comment: WebMarkupMin minification happens dynamically during runtime, so it's extra work to handle each request, right?

Comment: That's right. The  UseWebMarkupMin method in Configure gets called by the each request. @user764754