# ASP.NET Core 6 : webmarkupmin.aspnetcore6 not working in local and server?

Tags: asp.net-core

My project was created with .NET Core 6 and I added the webmarkupmin plugin to the project with the core 6 version, but it doesn't work both locally and on the server?

I used the codes in the link below, but it still didn't work

[webmarkupmin.aspnetcore5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65859075/how-to-minify-in-net-core-mvc-view)

I also used the following codes and it still didn't work.

```
builder.Services.AddWebMarkupMin()   
                .AddHtmlMinification()   
                .AddXmlMinification();
```

I added the following middleware to the `Program.cs` file

```
app.UseWebMarkupMin();
```

Comment: here is the sample code they have provided could you try to use that https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the checks I did, I found out that there was an extra double quotes  `"` inside my tag that caused it not to work.